# Communication between Windows Universal App and Desktop application (Win 10)

Tags: ipc, win-universal-app, background-agent

Is there any way to realize communication between a Windows Universal App and a standard Desktop application running at the same computer? I read that UAs don't support IPC. Instead they use those so called background agents. But is it possible to use those background agents not to communicate with a UA but rather a desktop application or is this completely suppressed?

The reason is, that I already have a desktop application and I would like to add Cortana support to it, without too much effort. So I would like to avoid converting the desktop app to a universal app. Cortana is only available in Universal Apps at the moment.

Comment: The answer is NO, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341707/communication-between-windows-store-app-and-native-desktop-application

Comment: OK, thank you very much. Too bad - that's not really sophisticated design, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with you, it's too bad, but they may provide a way to do that in future since there is already an app-to-app communication mechanism (as I just remembered!). I mean, when an app can communicate another app, a desktop app should be able to do that too! see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.appservice.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You may be able to call WinRT api in a desktop app too, see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx

Comment: While calling WinRT APIs from desktop apps is possible, it's only available for a subset of WinRT APIs. Cortana's APIs aren't included in that set, yet, they're not tagged with the appropriate flags that indicate they're safe to use (and they'll fail because you're not running in the context of a package). We're aware of the desire to use the APIs from a desktop app however, and we're considering options there.