# IPC Communication between Windows Universal App and Desktop application (Win 10)

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, ipc

We want to build a UWP C++ app that acts as GUI for an imaging application, to replace our current WPF desktop app.
Images could be acquired in a desktop app/service, because we need thirdy party desktop drivers (i.e. we use camera link frame grabbers).
We have big images to show (i.e. 25 mega pixels) at quite high frame rate (i.e. 30 frame per second).
Using http or udp to share images is too slow and a waste of resources.
 Using a shared memory could be the most efficient way.
We need to run our application on desktop PC only (not a really universal app...)
I know there is already this answer [Communication between Windows Universal App and Desktop application (Win 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129213/communication-between-windows-universal-app-and-desktop-application-win-10) but I would like to know if someone is aware of any news about IPC alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  I believe what you have seen (protocol definition on appxmanifest, or background task) is based on a a type of IPC (ALPC maybe?) that is MS specific.  Still the implementation lacks allot.  There is no other alternative.

If you only need to run on a desktop why would you want to make a UWP APP?  WPF on the full .NET Framework would be my choice for an app like that.